# how to reset a policy tag attached to a bigquery column?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm using a script to set policy tags to a bigquery column (e.g. name column) but I don't know how to proceed in order to rollback this change using a Python script

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud.bigquery.schema import SchemaField,PolicyTagList
client = bigquery.Client()

table_id = 'project_id.dataset_id.table_id'

policy_tags = PolicyTagList(names=["projects/<my_project_id>/locations/us/taxonomies/<taxonomy_id>/policyTags/<policy_tag_id>"])
table = client.get_table(table_id)

table.schema = [
        SchemaField(
            name="name",
            field_type="STRING",
            policy_tags=policy_tags
            ),
        SchemaField(
            name="age",
            field_type="INT64"
            )
        ]

table = client.update_table(table=table,fields=["schema"])
print(table.schema)
```

thanks in advance!

I tried to use policy_tags=None but it doesn't work (the attached policy doesn't get removed from column)

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#api_5

Answer (score 0):

policy_tags = PolicyTagList(names="")

did the trick!